# rearrange array keys php

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

i have this array:

```
Array
(
[15] =>     13.1

[16] =>     Mark one answer

[19] => You see a car on the hard shoulder of a motorway with a HELP pennant displayed. This means the driver is most likely to be

[20] => a disabled person first aid trained

[21] => a foreign visitor

[22] => a rescue patrol person

[25] => DES s15, HC r278);
```

How do i get it to sort the keys from 0?
to get this: i know there is a function, but my head is burned, the sort function doesn't fit my needs since they rearrange values, and  i need them to be conserved.

```
 Array
(
[0] =>  13.1

[1] =>  Mark one answer

[2] => You see a car on the hard shoulder of a motorway with a HELP pennant displayed. This means the driver is most likely to be

[3] => a disabled person first aid trained

[4] => a foreign visitor

[5] => a rescue patrol person

[6] => DES s15, HC r278);
```

Answer (score 62, accepted):

I think you're looking for [array_values](http://au.php.net/array_values)

`$arr = array_values($arr);`

Comment: It also looks like a `trim` was applied =) `array_map('trim', ...)` to the max.