# How to remove array elements without deleting the keys

Tags: php, arrays

I tried to remove few array elements from my PHP script using PHP's unset() built-in funciton.
here is the code, that I tried.

```
<?php

$my_array = array('.','..','one','two','three','four');

unset($my_array[1] , $my_array[0]);

echo '<pre>';

print_r($my_array);

echo '</pre>';

?>
```

Then I got this output.

```
Array
(
    [2] => one
    [3] => two
    [4] => three
    [5] => four
)
```

but this is not what I'm expected. I want somthing like this.

```
Array
(
    [0] => one
    [1] => two
    [2] => three
    [3] => four
)
```

how can I achive this? thanks.

Comment: So you want to remove "." and ".." that you got from `scan_dir` ? That's a different question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to Remove Array Element and Then Re-Index Array?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5217721/how-to-remove-array-element-and-then-re-index-array)

Comment: Either that or just [`array_shift()` twice](http://codepad.org/hK3AZ0ef)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

yes that is the correct behavior, if you want to reset the keys you can use `array_values()`

```
$my_array = array('.','..','one','two','three','four');
unset($my_array[1] , $my_array[0]);
$my_array = array_values($my_array);
```

Comment: You guys are quick today.

Answer (score 1):

```
unset($my_array[1] , $my_array[0]);
$my_array = array_values($my_array);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use array_shift() function to remove the first element (red) from an array, and return the value of the removed element. We can get output as has u excepted.

```
$a=array('.','..','one','two','three','four');
array_shift($a); //array('..','one','two','three','four');
array_shift($a); // array('one','two','three','four');
```

Use array_pop() function to deletes the last element of an array. We can get output as has u excepted.

```
$a=array('.','..','one','two','three','four');
array_pop()($a); // array('.','..','one','two','three');
array_pop()($a); // array('.','..','one','two');
```

Use this function, array is indexed from zero every time.
Otherwise use

```
$a= array('.','..','one','two','three','four');
unset($a[1] , $a[0]);
print_r(array_values(a));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$my_array = array('.','..','one','two','three','four');

unset($my_array[1] , $my_array[0]);

echo '<pre>';

print_r(array_values($my_array));

echo '</pre>';
```

Comment: Thanks problem solved :) but in your code 4th line shoud be correct

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you can find answer to your question in another:
[rearrange array keys php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8797710/rearrange-array-keys-php)

Just like it has been told, [array_values](http://php.net/array_values) would do the trick for you.

```
$arr = array_values($arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `array_values` fonction:

> From http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php